# Count non-null values in each row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
    site1   time1   site2   time2   site3   time3   site4   time4   site5   time5   ... time6   site7   time7   site8   time8   site9   time9   site10  time10  target
 session_id                                                                                 

21669   56  2013-01-12 08:05:57 55.0    2013-01-12 08:05:57 NaN NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT ... NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT 0
54843   56  2013-01-12 08:37:23 55.0    2013-01-12 08:37:23 56.0    2013-01-12 09:07:07 55.0    2013-01-12 09:07:09 NaN NaT ... NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT NaN NaT 0
77292   946 2013-01-12 08:50:13 946.0   2013-01-12 08:50:14 951.0   2013-01-12 08:50:15 946.0   2013-01-12 08:50:15 946.0   2013-01-12 08:50:16 ... 2013-01-12 08:50:16 948.0   2013-01-12 08:50:16 784.0   2013-01-12 08:50:16 949.0   2013-01-12 08:50:17 946.0   2013-01-12 08:50:17 0
114021  945 2013-01-12 08:50:17 948.0   2013-01-12 08:50:17 949.0   2013-01-12 08:50:18 948.0   2013-01-12 08:50:18 945.0   2013-01-12 08:50:18 ... 2013-01-12 08:50:18 947.0   2013-01-12 08:50:19 945.0   2013-01-12 08:50:19 946.0   2013-01-12 08:50:19 946.0   2013-01-12 08:50:20 0
```

I need to count N of columns, where site != NaN.
I try to use

```
df[['site%s' % i for i in range(1, 11)]].count(axis=1)
```

but it returns me 10 to every id

Also I have tried

```
train_df[sites].notnull().count(axis=1)
```

and it also didn't help.

Desire output

```
21669    2
54843    4
77292    10
114021   10
```

Comment: `train_df[sites].notnull().sum(axis=1)`? You only want to sum the `True` elements in your columns. Alternatively, use `train_df[sites].count(axis=1)`

Answer (score 45):

I'd do this with just `count`:

```
train_df[sites].count(axis=1)
```

`count` specifically counts non-null values. The issue with your current implementation is that `notnull` yields boolean values, and `bool`s are certainly not-null, meaning they are always counted.

---

```
df

        one       two     three four   five
a -0.166778  0.501113 -0.355322  bar  False
b       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN
c -0.337890  0.580967  0.983801  bar  False
d       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN
e  0.057802  0.761948 -0.712964  bar   True
f -0.443160 -0.974602  1.047704  bar  False
g       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN
h -0.717852 -1.053898 -0.019369  bar  False

df.count(axis=1)

a    5
b    0
c    5
d    0
e    5
f    5
g    0
h    5
dtype: int64
```

And...

```
df.notnull().count(axis=1)


a    5
b    5
c    5
d    5
e    5
f    5
g    5
h    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: it returns me 10 to every id

Comment: @PetrPetrov Try saving your file... See my edit, it works nicely.

Answer (score 10):

Also trading `count(axis=1)` for `sum()` should do the trick

```
train_df[sites].notnull().sum()
```

Comment: `train_df[sites].isnull().sum()` and `train_df[sites].isnull().any()` are two more useful idioms (first counts number of null values, and second shows if there are any nulls)

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to find the number of missing values by row-wise is :

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
```

To find the number of rows which are having more than 3 null values:

```
df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) >=3]
```

In case if you need to drop rows which are having more than 3 null values then you can follow this code:

```
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 3]
```